# Ruby: How to work with apostrophes in SQL query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am looping through a database and pulling strings that need to be queried. My challenge is that some of the strings have a single quote in them (IE. Devil's Elbow ) the SQL query needs to be in the following format 'string_goes_here'

How can I run a query on Devil's Elbow without breaking the query?

EDIT** I figured out how to run the query. You need to add another apostrophe beside the original (IE 'Devil''s Elbow').

How can I add logic in ruby for the second apostrophe to be added if there's an apostrophe in the string?

Thank you.

Comment: does it work if you just put double quotes around it and then have the single quote in there.  Can you give an actual example of what you are trying that isn't working?

Comment: @RockwellRice SQL query will not accept double quotations around the string. That's the issue. It has to be surrounded by single quotations.

Comment: Could you please add your query?

Comment: @itsmemrit you can wrap the string in `double quote`. i.e. `User.where('name like "Devil's Elbow"')`